# How to rotate d3 geo svg map

Tags: svg, d3.js

I want to rotate d3 svg map but I couldnt.

I used for projection this code:

```
var projection = d3.geo.stereographic()    
    .center([3.9,43.0])    
    .scale(2000)    
    .translate([width / 4 , height / 2]) ;
```

Here my map:
[turkey_map](http://kds.saglik.gov.tr/mp.png)

I want to rotate normally.But I couldt. When I use rotate([0,90]) function , its disappering:

How can we rotate this as normal ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the projection rotation is like rotating the whole globe 90 degrees. That's why Turkey disappears completely. Instead render everything in a g and rotate that elements using SVG transform.